# Firebase Realtime database security rules, blocking reading entire node

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is the structure of my firebase real time database. I want to block read access when accessing the whole words object but make it allowed when accessing single nodes in words. The purpose is preventing users from reading the whole words at once. How can i do it with security rules?

[image: My firebase database structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a [`$` wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "words": {
      ".read" false,
      "$word: {
        ".read" true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So on the entire `words` node the read is denied, but then the `$word` matches any child node of `words` an allows reading there.